# Связать две таблицы по произвольным столбцам

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails

Есть две таблицы, которые изначально были не связаны, необходимо связать их по произвольным столбцам типа integer. Подсказывали реализацию через foreign_key но не смог разобраться.
Задача не критична, так как через столбец с id через find без проблем можно получить нужный объект, однако хочется добавить более правильное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
belong_to :ralationName, :class_name=>'ActiveRecordModelClass', :foreign_key=>:field_name
```

has_many аналогично

Не помогает?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял что здесь 
ralationName - модель с которой связываем
ActiveRecordModelClass - класс модели
field_name - поле модели ralationName по которому хотим связать?
Попробовал сделать так, но результат как и был раньше, при обращении к полю получаем только id связанного объекта.

Допустим в модели А есть поле fieldForRel в котором хранится id соответствующий значению id модели B и мы хотим связать с моделью B по полю id, чтобы при обращении к объекту модели A (например objectA.fieldForRel) у нас был объект модели B с id из поля fieldForRel.

Comment: `relatioName` - это просто имя связи т.е. в текущей модели для доступа к связанной модели Вы используете myModel.relationName

`class_name` -> Класс модели "на той стороне"

`foreign_key` -> имя поля в текущей модели в которой хранится значение ключа на модель `class_name`

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, с именем связи оказывается я всё время тупил